# KDE start Thunderbird on specific Dekstop at startup

Tags: kde, startup, autostart

I want to start Thunderbird on a specific Desktop at startup of KDE.

I found the autostart settings but I did not find any option to start the program on a different Desktop.

How can I do this? Is there a command to start a program on a different Desktop that I could execute from a script at startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on titlebar ot ThunderBird, click `More Actions` -> `Special Application Settings` -> `Size & Position`.  Check the box to the left of `Desktop`, select 'Apply Initially' or 'Force' (depending on whether you might move it later) in the first dropdown, then the desktop you want in the second dropdown.